# Javascript find "/" and replace with "_"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function, ecmascript-6

I am stuck doing this. I am working with a CMS built in ASP.net and have strings I want to find "/" and replace with "_", how do I do this?
Tried without success:

```
str.replace(/\//g), '/');
str.replace(//\/g), '/');
```

Thanks

Comment: `str.replace(/\//g, '_');`

Answer (score 1):

Try to simple

```
var str = "/Shohel Rana/".replace(/[/]/g, "_");
console.log(str);
```

If you want to replace space, _ or add more Then add character into the third bracket.

```
var str = "/something / test".replace(/[\s,/]/g, "_");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

What your current code is doing is replacing all occurrences of `/` with `/` - it's not doing anything at all. You need to replace the occurrences with `_`:

```js
var str = "One/Two/Three";
str = str.replace(/\//g, '_');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "/something / test"
str = str.replace(/\//g, '_')
console.log(str)
```